# Display all images in a folder without testing for file exist

Tags: php, image

Using the following code, I am able to display up to 10 images. What I want is to be able to display all images in the folder without going through an infinite loop and without testing if the image file exist at each loop.

```
for($i=1; $i<=10; $i++)
{
 $filename = "/folder/$i.jpg";
 echo "
  <img title='$i' src='$filename'>
 ";
}
```

Assuming that I have no idea how many images there are in the folder and that I do not want to store this information in a database, how would you display all the images with file names are that are integers ending with a `.jpg` extension?

Comment: I would use RecursiveDirectoryIterator http://au.php.net/manual/en/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php

Comment: @b.b3rn4rd, can you put down as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
//path to directory to scan

$directory = "/folder/";

//get all image files with a .jpg extension.

$images = glob($directory . "*.jpg");
```

UPDATE
reference: http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php

Comment: Why not to link to an [official documentation](http://php.net/glob), rather than to some unknown site?

Answer (score 4):

I would use RecursiveDirectoryIterator 
http://au.php.net/manual/en/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php
if use use glob you will have to handle recursion manually.

```
$path = '/path/to/folder';

/* @var $file SplFileInfo */
foreach (new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
    new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($path)) as $file) {
    if ($file->isFile() 
        && in_array(strtolower($file->getExtension()), array('jpg', 'png', 'gif'))) {
        echo $file->getPathname()."\n";
    }
}
```

Please note that: SplFileInfo::getExtension is available from PHP 5.3.6

Comment: From the link, it wasn't very clear how this works. Can you expand your answer with an example? Thanks. And in what way is this better than the `glob()` function?

Comment: I've put an example in my answer

Comment: I see. +1 for you. This functionality would come in handy if I am searching for files buried within multiple folders. `Glob()` seems to be sufficient for my requirement as of now. Anyway, thanks for showing me the alternative :)